# C++ palindrome function

Tags: c++, function, palindrome

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome(string str)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= str.length()-1; i++)
    {
        if(str[i] != str[str.length()-1-i])
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    string text;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter some Text: " << endl;
        cin >> text;
        if(isPalindrome(text))
        {
            cout << "The text is a palindrome" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The text is not a palindrome" << endl;
        }

    }while(text != "Q");

    return 0;
}
```

**Input_1**

```
otto
```

Output

```
The text is a palindrome
```

**Input_2**

```
 ottop
```

Output

```
The text is a palindrome
```

**Input_3**

```
ottopo
```

Output3

```
The text is a palindrome
```

I want to check the string entered from user is palindrome or not ? Why Output for my 3rd input is getting wrong ? I think I am missing something.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `return` returns from a function.

Comment: For one thing, `return` returns from your function. That means your loop only runs the first iteration, the `return` statements cause it to return during that iteration and it'll never go any further than the first/last character comparison.

Answer (score 4):

You are returning true on the first iteration of the loop.  And you only need to iterate on half the string.

Corrected:

```
    size_t len = str.length();

    for(int i = 0; i < len/2; i++){
        if(str[i] != str[len-1-i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to have a `return true` after the else statement there. Put that outside the for loop and your code should work.

As an extra nitpick, you don't have to check until strlen(s) - 1, but strlen(s) / 2 is actually enough. I'll leave figuring that out to you, as it's quite straightforward and not too different from what you are doing, at all.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been said, the `return true;` should not be in the `else`, but after the end of the `for` loop. This can also be accomplished in just a few lines. A string is a palindrome if it is the same reversed as it is normally. All you need is

```
reversedText = reverse(text.begin(), text.end());
if (text == reversedText)
    //indicate that it is a palindrome
else
    //indicate that it is not a palindrome`
```

Just be sure to include algorithm. I can understand if you don't want to use a library for some reason, but I just want to make sure that you know that this can be accomplished very easily.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I know it could be done very easily with library functions, but sometimes it's good practice to do it the "hard" way!

Comment: @BamBam281189 I understand that. I've done similar things many times. I believe it helps me to get to know the language better.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a flag to `1` if it is not a palindrome, then break after:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len/2; i++) {
    if (str[i] != str[len-1-i]) {
        // here .......
    }
```

Comment: Just don't give answers if you want to. Put some effort see what mistake done by user who asked Question also go through given answers by other users & if you still find that you are contributing something better and different from other answers then answer.